# How to change a string I get from API

Tags: swift, string, swiftui

I get a string with a date of the first flight for each of four rockets from [this API](https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets). The string that I get looks like this: "**2006-03-24**". I want it to look this way: "**24 March, 2006**". I don't understand how to do this in SwiftUI.

My View with the dates:

```
struct DateView: View {
    @State var rockets = [RocketInfo]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if rockets.isEmpty {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                TabView {
                    ForEach(rockets) { rocket in
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("First flight")
                                Spacer()
                                Text(rocket.firstFlight)
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page)
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            InfoApi().getRockets { rockets in
                self.rockets = rockets
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DateView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the API data: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DurPq.png)

Comment: What type does RocketInfo.firstFlight have? Are you passing it into a date in the model, or are you keeping it as a string? (Relevant because if you’re parsing it into a Date, it’s easy to do what you want with DateFormatter, but if it’s a raw string, we first need to make sure it’s parsed correctly).

Comment: @adeasismont, I get it from API as a string and it parses correctly – as I checked the API itself.

Comment: So RocketInfo.firstFlight is a Date object? In that case, please just have a look at DateFormatter, it’ll do what you want! https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

Comment: @adeasismont, no, unfortunately it's not a Date object, it's a String object. In API it looks like this – "2006-03-24", and so I get it from there the same kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The func gets a date from the string, which you then can format to your wishes.

```
    var body: some View {
        let dateString = "2006-03-24"
        let date = dateFromString(dateString)
        
        Text("\(date, style: .date)")
    }
    
    func dateFromString(_ string: String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = .current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter.date(from: string) ?? Date()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two instances of DateFormatter - one to convert the string from API to a Date instance and the other to convert the date instance to your desired string format.

```swift
let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter() 
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // Format of API Date

let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter() 
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "d MMMM, yyyy" // Desired Format

let date = dateFormatter1.date(from: "2006-03-24")!
let desiredFormat = dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
print(desiredFormat) // prints "24 March, 2006"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I encourage you to change `firstFlight` in `RocketInfo` to be a `Date` object, to get the correct data representation in the model. You may have to configure your JSONDecoder to parse the date string correctly:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
```

Then, you need another `DateFormatter` when you want to convert that date back into a string:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM, yyyy"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: object.firstFlight)
```

Please see here for the list of custom formats supported by `DateFormatter`:
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

(There's also a couple of system defined formats, please see `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` in the docs.)